# Dockertest + postgres + golang. relation "url_uuid" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, golang, docker

Для своего микросервиса (сервис общается с postgres без ошибок) решил сделать тест с использованием dockertest.
Пример использование взял отсюда - https://github.com/ory/dockertest/blob/v3/examples/PostgreSQL.md
В postgres на данный момент существует BD с таблицей url_uuid, но при запуске Test_1 в err получаю ошибку - **pq: relation "url_uuid" does not exist**

Что я делаю не так? -_-

```
package postgres

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/ory/dockertest/v3"
    "github.com/ory/dockertest/v3/docker"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

var db *sql.DB

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // uses a sensible default on windows (tcp/http) and linux/osx (socket)
    pool, err := dockertest.NewPool("")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not connect to docker: %s", err)
    }

    // pulls an image, creates a container based on it and runs it
    resource, err := pool.RunWithOptions(&dockertest.RunOptions{
        Repository: "postgres",
        Tag:        "latest",
        Env: []string{
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test",
            "POSTGRES_USER=test",
            "POSTGRES_DB=DB",
            "listen_addresses = '*'",
        },
    }, func(config *docker.HostConfig) {
        // set AutoRemove to true so that stopped container goes away by itself
        config.AutoRemove = true
        config.RestartPolicy = docker.RestartPolicy{Name: "no"}
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not start resource: %s", err)
    }

    hostAndPort := resource.GetHostPort("5432/tcp")
    databaseUrl := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://test:test@%s/DB?sslmode=disable", hostAndPort)

    log.Println("Connecting to database on url: ", databaseUrl)

    resource.Expire(120) // Tell docker to hard kill the container in 120 seconds

    // exponential backoff-retry, because the application in the container might not be ready to accept connections yet
    pool.MaxWait = 120 * time.Second
    if err = pool.Retry(func() error {
        db, err = sql.Open("postgres", databaseUrl)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return db.Ping()
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not connect to docker: %s", err)
    }
    //Run tests
    code := m.Run()

    // You can't defer this because os.Exit doesn't care for defer
    if err := pool.Purge(resource); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not purge resource: %s", err)
    }
    os.Exit(code)
}

func Test_1(t *testing.T) {
    _, err := db.Exec("select * from url_uuid")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не создаете таблицу в базе данных. Вы ведь поднимаете новый контейнер с postgres, а не подключаетесь к уже существующей БД.

То есть, можно сделать так:

```go
if _, err := db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE url_uuid (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);`); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Could not create table: %s", err)
}
```

Но лучше вынести создание схемы в отдельный файл и применять его перед запуском тестов:

```sql
// schema.sql
CREATE TABLE url_uuid (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

```go
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // ...

    // apply schema
    schema, err := ioutil.ReadFile("schema.sql")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not read schema: %s", err)
    }
    if _, err := db.Exec(string(schema)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not apply schema: %s", err)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Это было неочевидно для меня.